# I can hardly remember the code for CASE SENSITIVITY in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

For example I input a name in a textbox in UPPER case.

Ex.  JOHN

Then what the program requires is in LOWER case.

Ex. john

But still the program accepted the UPPER cased text.

I know there's an import or declaration that could be added for that.
I think its in the **InitializeComponent**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh .. what does user input from a textbox have to do with "code CASE SENSITIVITY"?

Comment: I'm still not sure what is meant. There is VB.NET code, and then text that the user enters into a textbox.. make sure to update the original question with clarifications. For example, what is this 'textbox'?

Comment: what I only remember is that that "code" is  put on top of all the codes (declaration)

Comment: okay I found it. its OPTION COMPARE. my problem now is how to use it?

Comment: Like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f.aspx?

Comment: ohh cool I answered my question.

Comment: its OPTION COMPARE TEXT.

Comment: thanks for the link sir. i'll check on that later for additional info.

Comment: Cool. You can also answer it down below (and then accept it).

Comment: okay so I still have a problem. its not working how I want it to.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If `TextBox1` contains "JOHN" then `If TextBox1.Text = "john"` will return False (even with changing `Option Compare`). Can you edit your question to add some code that tries to do what you want and explain how it fails?

Comment: i'm referring to a password.

Comment: ex. password = John

if I entered "JOHN" which is in UPPER case. then it should return as false.

if textbox1.text = "John" then

form2.show

else

label1.text = "incorrect password"

end if

Answer (score -1):

OPTION COMPARE TEXT

it is put on top of all your codes.
on the initialization part